# React <details> - have only one open at a time

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with several  elements. I'm trying to figure out how to update the code with hooks so that only one  element will be open at a time - when a  element is open, the other's should be closed. This is the code:

```
const HowItWorks = ({ content, libraries }) => {
  const Html2React = libraries.html2react.Component;
  return (
    <HowItWorksContainer>
      {content.fields.map((tab, i) => {
        const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
        const onToggle = () => {
          setOpen(!open);
        };
        return (
          <details
            key={i}
            onToggle={onToggle}
            className={`tab ${open ? "open" : "closed"}`}
          >
            <summary className="tab__heading">
              <div className="wrapper">
                <p>{tab.heading}</p>
                {open ? (
                  <i className="icon kap-arrow-minus" />
                ) : (
                  <i className="icon kap-arrow-plus" />
                )}
              </div>
            </summary>
            <div className="tab__content">
              <Html2React html={tab.content} />
            </div>
          </details>
        );
      })}
    </HowItWorksContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the `open` state be a boolean, make it be the ID of the element that is open. Then you can have a function that returns if the element is open by comparing the state with the ID.

```
const HowItWorks = ({ content, libraries }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(0); //Use the element ID to check which one is open

  const onToggle = (id) => {
      setOpen(id);
  };

  const isOpen = (id) => {
     return id === open ? "open" : "closed";
  }

  const Html2React = libraries.html2react.Component;
  return (
    <HowItWorksContainer>
      {content.fields.map((tab, i) => {
        return (
          <details
            key={i}
            onToggle={onToggle}
            className={`tab ${isOpen(i)}`}
          >
            <summary className="tab__heading">
              <div className="wrapper">
                <p>{tab.heading}</p>
                {!!isOpen(i) ? (
                  <i className="icon kap-arrow-minus" />
                ) : (
                  <i className="icon kap-arrow-plus" />
                )}
              </div>
            </summary>
            <div className="tab__content">
              <Html2React html={tab.content} />
            </div>
          </details>
        );
      })}
    </HowItWorksContainer>
  );
};
```